# Embedded dashboard in home tab using iframe, can't open hyperlinks from it

Tags: administration, customization, dashboard

I added a dashboard as a home page component and it displays fine, but I am unable to open links to records when clicking on them in the dashboard.  I'd love to do a "target=_top" type deal but that doesn't work.  This is the code for the component:

`<iframe src="/01Z40000000sJer?isdtp=vw" frameborder="0" height="1300" width="1280" align="center"></iframe>`

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks!

edit - The iframe is used to display the entire dashboard in the home tab instead of the standard component's only displaying the top row.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not displaying the dashboard as part of the standard component and using an Iframe instead ?

Comment: Yes, to display an entire dashboard in the home tab instead of only the top row

Comment: Do the hyperlinks not work at all, or do they open within the confines of the iframe?

Comment: They don't work at all

Answer (score 1):

I believe the isdtp=vw is a service console URL hack and as part of its behavior it adds the srcUp function to any links in the page.  Since you are not displaying in the console, the links would not work.  My only success with this type of effort was to create a custom vf page dashboard and include that on the homepage.